# Scrolling to the bottom of a div after the first call of Setinterval()

Tags: javascript, ajax

I made a comment section with a fixed height and `overflow-y: scroll` and I want to load there  some comments with a `setInterval` function.

The problem with my code is, that every second the `updateMessages` is called, it scrolls me to the bottom and I can't scroll up, because every second I'm sent back to the bottom. 
How to do it to load the messages with the scrolled div and just after that start the `setinterval` function without scrolling down?

```html
<script>
  setInterval(function(){
    updateMessages();
  },1000);
  function updateMessages(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'includes/display_discussions.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>',
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(show_messages){
                 if(!show_messages.error){                               
                   $("#scroll_down").html(show_messages);
                   var div = document.getElementById("scroll_down");
                   div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
                 }
               }
    });
   }    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could toggle a boolean once the messages are loaded, and use that to only scroll in the first case. Then you could call the `updateMessages` once manually when the page loads, and `setInterval` to call it every 30 seconds:

```
var messagesLoaded = false;

function updateMessages() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'includes/display_discussions.php?id=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>',
    type: "POST",
    success: function(show_messages) {
      if (!show_messages.error) {
        $("#scroll_down").html(show_messages);

        if (!messagesLoaded) {
          messagesLoaded = true;
          var div = document.getElementById("scroll_down");
          div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateMessages);

setInterval(updateMessages, 30000);
```

Comment: I would like to call the function every 30 seconds or something like that. The problem is that when I go to this page, the messages aren't loaded yet, and the div can't be scrolled to bottom. So what to change in order to scroll down JUST when the message are loaded for the first time?

Comment: Lots of thanks mate! I was looking for an answer for 2 hours! Have a nice day :)